# Understanding of nested class

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the below code:

```
public class StudentManager {
 
    public Student find(String studentID) throws StudentNotFoundException {
        if (studentID.equals("123456")) {
            return new Student();
        } else {
            throw new StudentNotFoundException(
                "Could not find student with ID " + studentID);
        }
    }
}
```

`public Student find(String studentID) throws StudentNotFoundException` - is this `public Student` a nested class? And then we used `find(String studentID)` a method? Can anyone please help me interpret this code? I am following [this link](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/exception/how-to-create-custom-exceptions-in-java) for understanding custom exception handling.

Update:

```
public class StudentTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentManager manager = new StudentManager();
 
        try {
 
            Student student = manager.find("0000001");
 
        } catch (StudentNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.print(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a nested class. It is a public instance method accepting a `studentID` parameter as a `String` that returns a `Student` and might throw a `StudentNotFoundException`.

Comment: Can we use its return type as String or Int instead of Student?

Comment: Do you want to change the return type?

Comment: @AHF In this case no, since the function returns a value of type `Student`. But it is possible for functions to return `String` and any other type.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually calling it `Student student = manager.find("0000001");` so we are making object of this function here? or instance of method Student? Is this Student a user defined data type?

Comment: Both `Student` and `StudentManager` appear to be user-defined classes. In `Student student = manager.find("000001");`, `manager` is most likely an instance of Class "StudentManager". The method `find(String)` of the `manager` instance is called with `"000001"` as parameter. Looking at how this `find` method was programmed, it will throw a `StudentNotFoundException` in this situation.

Comment: But `Student` is value type not class ?

Comment: Student is likely a user defined class. It is also the return type of the method.

Comment: Then Student is a class with in a Student Manager class, why it is not nested then

Comment: `Student student = manager.find("0000001");` assigns the return value of `manager.find` to the variable student.

Comment: "Then Student is a class with in a Student Manager class"-are you showing us all of the relevant code? From what you have shown, it seems that `Student` is defined in a separate Java file.

Comment: I am following this link https://www.codejava.net/java-core/exception/how-to-create-custom-exceptions-in-java as tutorial

Comment: It looks like they may have defined `Student` in a previous lesson or have simply omitted it as it is not important for understanding the lesson.